# How can I use a javaScript function to call the rowEditor button for the latest row added to my datatable?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, jsf, primefaces

```
        <p:commandButton value="Add" icon="ui-icon-plus"
            actionListener="#{institutionView.addInst}" oncomplete="PF('institutionDataTable').addRow()" process="@this"/>
        <p:growl id="message" showDetail="true" />


  <p:dataTable id="instDisplay" var="institutionData" paginator="true"
                rows="15" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,25,30"
                widgetVar="institutionDataTable"
                filteredValue="#{institutionView.institutionData}"
                emptyMessage="No institutions with given criteria"
                value="#{institutionView.institutionData}" selectionMode="single"
                selection="#{institutionView.selectedModel}"
                rowSelectListener="#{institutionView.onRowSelect}"
                onRowSelectUpdate="instDisplay"
                rowKey="#{institutionData.institutionId}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                editable="true">

         <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{institutionView.onRowEdit}"
                    update="instDisplay" />
         <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"
                    listener="#{institutionView.onRowCancel}" update="msg" />

         ... columns

       <p:column headerText="Edit" style="width:32px">
          <p:rowEditor />
       </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
```

I want to call a javascript function to click the p:rowEditor for the latest row that has been added by my commandButton. This must happen sumaltaneously as the row is created it must be in edit mode. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES.  Go to the showcase page here and press F12 to bring up JavaScript console.

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/addRow.xhtml

If you inspect the HTML of the very last row where the Edit Row icon is you will see this HTML.

```
<td role="gridcell" style="width:32px">
    <div id="form:cars1:14:j_idt655" class="ui-row-editor ui-helper-clearfix">
        <a href="#" class="ui-row-editor-pencil">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-row-editor-check">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check ui-c"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-row-editor-close">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close ui-c"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</td>
```

You will notice in `form:cars1:14:j_idt655` that 14 is the row number of the last row.

Now in the JavaScript console type or paste this command and press ENTER.

```
$('#form\\:cars1\\:14\\:j_idt655 > .ui-row-editor-pencil').click();
```

Notice it opens the last row for editing??  So now you just need to find out your new row when you add it for the row number.  Each Row has a data-ri element on the TR like so..

```
<tr data-ri="14" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd" role="row">
```

So to get the last row in the table and press its Edit button enter the following script in the javaScript console.

```
// select the last row number
var row = $("tr[data-ri]").last().attr('data-ri');
// click the edit pencil
$('#form\\:cars1\\:'+row+'\\:j_idt655 > .ui-row-editor-pencil').click();
```

So change your oncomplete JS function to something like this note you will have to update your #form to be your form name and j_idt655 to be your proper component id...

```
function addRowAndEdit() {
   PF('institutionDataTable').addRow();
   // select the last row number
   var row = $("tr[data-ri]").last().attr('data-ri');
   // click the edit pencil
   $('#form\\:instDisplay\\:'+row+'\\:j_idt655 > .ui-row-editor-pencil').click();
};
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work, as my datatable does not update when the row is added. It only displays the updated row once i refresh my page.

Comment: Then you have a different issue.  The AddRow should show up immediately just like in the showcase example here:  https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/addRow.xhtml   If yours does not work like that you have some other problem in your code.